# Проблема с разрешением web speach

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго времени суток, делаю что-то вроде приложения, есть html, css, js, хотел добавить web speech от chrome. Код представлен ниже, хотя основная проблема мне кажется не в нем.

Проблема в том что chrome почему-то считает мою многострадальческую html-ку незащищенным соединением и наотрез отказывается поверить в обратное, помогите решить пожалуйста.

Если что #speach - это простой button.

```
$('#speach').on("click", startRecognizer);

function startRecognizer(){
   if ('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window) {
     var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
     recognition.lang = 'ru';

     recognition.onresult = function (event) {
        var result = event.results[event.resultIndex];
        console.clear();
        console.log(result[0].transcript);
     };

    recognition.onend = function() {
       console.log('Распознавание завершилось.');
    };

   recognition.start();
   } else alert('webkitSpeechRecognition не поддерживается :(')
}
```

Да на всякий случай предвосхищая ответы ссылающиеся на мою полнейшую неумность,скажу (а заодно и вставлю картинки) что переключать chrome-ские ползунки всячески пробовал, но он не слушается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем, я нашел решение, не самое изящное, но вдруг кому-нибудь в будущем пригодиться (только поэтому и пишу :) ).

Думаю многие знают что на github есть один бесплатный хостинг. Вообщем им я и воспользовался, залил всё на него, и потом уже зашел прямо на этот хост и проверил.

Код кстати рабочий, всё работает отлично ).